# Resolving system environment variable using Spring Expression Language

Tags: spring, environment-variables, spring-el

I want to resolve system environment variable using `Spring Expression Language' in spring servlet configuration file. My first approach was:

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
     class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
     p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.#{systemEnvironment.THREAD_ENV}.properties" />
```

This is throwing below exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 18): Field or property 'THREAD_ENV' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap'
```

Then I have tried:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.#{systemEnvironment['THREAD_ENV']}.properties" />
```

and

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.#{systemEnvironment[THREAD_ENV]}.properties" />
```

which both fail and resolve to empty string. I am using Tomcat6 and I export this variable just before restarting Tomcat server:

```
export THREAD_ENV=live;
/etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart;
```

Would like to mention that all three methods work on some of my Tomcat6 instances but not on all - what could be the reason of such a strange behaviour? Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

The SpEL variable is `systemProperties`, not `systemEnvironment`.

```xml
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.#{systemProperties['THREAD_ENV']}.properties" />
```

Comment: would this work with OS system variables? I expect it to work only with jvm properties - anyway I have tried it and my variable is resolved again to empty string.

Comment: Spring provides both `systemProperties` and `systemEnvironment`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis where did you find that? The only reference I can find is an oblique reference at [Spring API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html) which I assume (but it's not explicit) relates to SpEL and says 'systemEnvironment' is from the OS and 'systemProperties' is from the JVM. My brief test confirms the latter, but I can't get the Windows envvars with systemEnvironment.

Comment: @Adam Most likely in the source code. I'll have to get back to you.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis found it - it's in [Spring API entry for PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) and I was unwittingly using the out-of-date plain ol' PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Had to upgrade the schema ref to spring-context-3.1.xsd and the propertyConfigurer class to org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and suddenly it worked. Spent way too long googling on "SpEL"

Comment: @Adam Take a look at [`StandardEnvironment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html) as well. It is the base class of most `Environment` types.